# remove special characters in string except alphabets

Tags: c

Spaces and digits are counted as special characters. Output must be in upper case.

```
printf("\n\nRemove characters in String Except Alphabets :\n");
printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");

printf("Input the string : ");
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);  
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    while (!((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z' || str[i] == '\0')))
    {
        for (j = i; str[j] != '\0'; ++j)
        {
            str[j] = str[j + 1];
        }
        str[j] = '\0';
    }
    ch = islower(str[i]) ? toupper(str[i]) : tolower(str[i]);
    putchar(ch);
}

printf("After removing the Output String : %s\n\n", str);
```

How to add upper cases?

Comment: just do: `for( char *s = str; *s; s++ ) if( isalpha(*s) ) putchar(toupper(*s));`

Comment: or: `char *e = str; for( char *s = str; *s; s++ ) if( isalpha(*s) ) *e++ = *s; *e = '\0';`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you have achieved. Try for one which does not require input, i.e. it should use hardcoded initialised variables so that the misbehaviour is demonstrated. Consider describing your findings when debugging the line `ch = islower(str[i]) ? toupper(str[i]) :
    tolwer(str[i]);` (I mean, apart from not compiling because of the typo...).

Comment: Please explain your thinking for this line `ch = islower(str[i]) ? toupper(str[i]) :
    tolwer(str[i]);` I read "If lower make upper, otherwise (i.e. if upper) make lower with a typo)." What is your plan here?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
ch = islower(str[i]) ? toupper(str[i]) : tolwer(str[i]);
```

with

```
ch = islower(str[i]) ? toupper(str[i]) : str[i];
```

Because what you have is
"if lower make upper, otherwise (i.e. if not lower, probably upper or special...) make lower, with a typo".  I.e. more of a toggle than of a make-upper.
And what you want is
"if lower make upper, otherwise keep".

However (as admittedly the busybee had to point out to me), you do not need a condition at all, because `toupper()` does not change an upper case character and hence the desired result can be achieved much more conveniently with

```
ch = toupper(str[i]);
```

Comment: But if the result is always upper case, why at all use a condition? `toupper()` does not change a character if it is already upper case.

Comment: @thebusybee Hmm, good point. ;-) I will incorporate your contribution into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Converting an `unsigned char` to uppercase is performed with `toupper()`.

Note that your code is too complicated: instead of 3 nested loops, you should use two index variables, one for reading the next character and one for writing the converted character if not special.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i, j;

    printf("\n\nRemove characters in String Except Alphabets :\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    printf("Input the string : ");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    for (i = j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        unsigned char c = str[i];  // avoid potential problems with signed char
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            str[j++] = toupper(c);
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';  // set the null terminator if the string is shorter.
    printf("After removing the Output String: %s\n\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```